# Assigning onclick function to radio buttons having the same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Here is my onclick event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#qual_years_<?php echo $qualification['hash'];?>").hide();
         jQuery("#qual_<?php echo $qualification['hash'];?>").on('click',updateYears);
});
```

Here are my radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" style="width:inherit;" id="qual_'.$qualification['hash'].'" name="qual_'.$qualification['hash'].'" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" style="width:inherit" id="qual_'.$qualification['hash'].'" name="qual_'.$qualification['hash'].'" value="0"/>
```

Here is my function being assigned:

```
function updateYears()
 {
    var id = '#qual_years_'+jQuery(this).attr('id').replace('qual_','');                
    if(jQuery(this).val() != 1){            
        jQuery(id).hide();
    } else {
        jQuery(id).show();
    }
 }
```

The problem is, **it only gets attached to the first input**. How do I attach it to both `radio inputs`. I cannot give two separate ids as the backend processing accounts for the one id.

Comment: Two elements should never have the same `id` within the same document.

Comment: Use `class` instead of `id`

Comment: Search for the name like `$('[name=abc123]')`. HTML elements are not supposed to have the same id. An id is an identifier, therefore it should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each()` method, here is a sample:

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul

$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Read more at [OFFICIAL DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up name and id.  The two elements should not have the same id.  They should have the same name if they are part of the same radiogroup.  This means that when you submit the form to the backend it is always based on name and not id.  So when you access the radio button based on the name in the backend it will return the value of the radio button that was selected when the form was submitted.